# FB APP: allow inapp invites to non app using fb users

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, structure

I'm stuck with this 'big picture' problem:

In a fb-integrated web app I'm making, users can create little groups consisting of a couple of friends. They can invite a friend by sending a link (url).

Users should be able to invite every friend they have. In fact, there are 2 types of friends:

- The ones who also use the app
- The ones who don't use the app (yet)

I'm having a hard time figuring out a way to invite the latter ( the group of non-app using friends)

First of all, the **fb graph api doesn't give acces to non-app using friends**. By labeling my app as a 'game', and by setting up the canvas, I can however get the 'invitable friends', i.e. the friends who don't play the game yet

But a problem remains: I can't send a **private message** to an invitable friend, as I don't have their user id ( only a token to perform a game invite)

By sending a **game invite**, An invited user would simply be **redirected to the fb canvas app**, without entering the right group

I could use the fb **share dialogbox**, but then users have select the friends using the fb dialogbox ui, which strongly interferes with my mobile app's flow.

I hope you're getting to understand my problem. I'm interested in hearing your thoughts about this.

Comment: check this answer, it'll also help you figure out more about the issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20561402/send-personal-messages-to-facebook-user-by-native-ios-app

Answer (score 1):

Just recently I had the same issue with the Graph API. I also wanted to particularly address non-app using friends to invite them to my iOS app. It's not a canvas app, so I didn't have access to the *invitable friend API* and also found that this is not a trivial issue.

anyway, if you're only interested in sending a message, i guess this is possible. this just wouldn't be an actual *invite* to the app, but rather really just a regular [facebook message](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share?locale=de_DE#message-dialog). do you need more info?

Comment: A message to non-app using friends? How exactly did you manage to do this?

Comment: did you check the link? it explains how message sending can be done to any friend.

Comment: @vrijdrogenaam did you get it? anything still unclear?